# Running parallel test with PNunit, can't read from config file

Tags: visual-studio-2013, webdriver, nunit, browserstack, pnunit

I wanna run pararell tests in Browserstack. This is my test project

RTest (Unit test project in VS 2013)

-UnitTest1.cs

-RTest.config

I open Nunit and browse to my dll bin/debug/RTest.dll and Nunit finds my test case

Problem
My RTest.config file looks like this:

```
<TestGroup>
  <ParallelTests>
      <ParallelTest>
        <Name>Testing</Name>
        <Tests>
          <TestConf>
            <Name>TestFF-20-Win8</Name>
            <Assembly>RTest.dll</Assembly>
            <TestToRun>RTest.UnitTest1.TestCase</TestToRun>
            <Machine>localhost:8080</Machine>
            <TestParams>
                <string>firefox</string> <!--browserName -->
                <string>20.0</string> <!-- version -->
                <string>Windows</string><!-- os -->
                <string>8</string><!-- os_version -->
            </TestParams>
          </TestConf>
          <TestConf>
            <Name>TestFF-21-win7</Name>
            <Assembly>RTest.dll</Assembly>
            <TestToRun>Test.UnitTest1.TestCase</TestToRun>
            <Machine>localhost:8080</Machine>
            <TestParams>
              <string>firefox</string>
              <!--browserName -->
              <string>21.0</string>
              <!-- version -->
              <string>Windows</string>
              <!-- os -->
              <string>7</string>
              <!-- os_version -->
            </TestParams>
          </TestConf>
        </Tests>
      </ParallelTest>
  </ParallelTests>
</TestGroup>
```

My UnitTest1.cs looks like this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using PNUnit.Framework;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace RTest
{
    [TestFixture()]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private string[] testParams;

        [SetUp]
        public void Init()
        {
            testParams = PNUnitServices.Get().GetTestParams();
            String params1 = String.Join(",", testParams);
            Console.WriteLine(params1);
            String browser = testParams[0];
            String version = testParams[1];
            String os = testParams[2];
            String os_version = testParams[3];
            DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.SetCapability("browserName", browser);
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, version);
            capability.SetCapability("os", os);
            capability.SetCapability("os_version", os_version);
            capability.SetCapability("browserstack.user", "testUser");
            capability.SetCapability("browserstack.key", "testPW");

            Console.WriteLine("Capabilities" + capability.ToString());

            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub/"), capability);
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
            StringAssert.Contains("Google", driver.Title);
            IWebElement query = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));
            query.SendKeys("Browserstack");
            query.Submit();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Cleanup()
        {
            driver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my test I recieve mInstance is null......
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No one who can help me out here?

Comment: Where you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming `RTest.config` to `test.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

PNunit is from long time not maintained. I found a new open-source distributed runner that can run NUnit tests in distributed and in-parallel, you can check the projects [documentation](http://docs.meissarunner.com/).

In general you have test controller and test agents. The test agents run your tests.
First start the server

> meissa.exe initServer

2. Start the test agent on the same or multiple machines:

> meissa.exe testAgent --testAgentTag="APIAgent"
>   --testServerUrl="http://IPServerMachine:5000"

3. Run your tests pointing the server URL

> meissa.exe runner --resultsFilePath="pathToResults\result.trx"
>   --outputFilesLocation="pathToBuildedFiles" 
>   --agentTag="NUnit" --testTechnology="MSTestCore" 
>   --testLibraryPath="pathToBuildedFiles\SampleTestProj.dll"

It is great since you don't need any configuration files or changing your code at all. It can work with both .NET Framework and .NET Core projects.